# Square Up API Edge Browser Issue

Tags: square-connect

I'm facing an issue right now with the SquareUp API. I'm using this function to render the form `paymentForm.build();` and everything works ok on all browers but on Edge Browser version 9 the form isn't rendering.

When you open the developer tools the form renders. Is there any kind of workaround to solve this issue in Edge browser?

Thanks!

Comment: It works when you open the developer tools on Edge? Seems like it is javascript blocking issue, but it is strange that it works with other browsers. If you reload the page with developer tools open do you see any errors, or does it work immediately?

Comment: Yes it works when I open the developer tools. I did test and cleaned the console.log references, also put the cache:false on the ajax calls but the problem seems to be still there. I'm also noticed that the problems replicate on others browsers like Firefox (sometimes) accordly with clients feedback.

Is there any other suggerence I could try?, the problem is with the rendering and build() function. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is facing this issue the answser is simple. It was as simple as adding the minimum height for the fields used by the iframe in SquareUp. Some browsers sometimes fails to render the form in the DOM, so adding a minimum height we assure that the fields are visible to the users until we wait for the iframe response.